# Is it Ok to use mongoDB passwordless?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am planning to install mongodb and the windows service which is connecting to it to the same machine. 
That machine will be in isolated network.

When we do it like that. 
Is it ok to connect local mongodb passwordless?

My planned properties will be like this...

```
private MongoDatabase _db;
public MongoDatabase DB
{
    get
    {
        if (_db == null)
        {
            var mongoServer = MongoServer.Create();
            _db = mongoServer.GetDatabase("myStatistics");
        }
        return _db;
    }
}

private MongoCollection _collection;
public MongoCollection Collection
{
    get { return _collection ?? (_collection = DB.GetCollection("myStats")); }
}
```

Comment: Database authentication adds an extra layer of security. There is zero drawback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Password-less in trusted environment
2. Password protected

It's okay to use MongoDB with auth disabled in trusted network. MongoDb developers [recommend](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-RunningWithoutSecurity%28TrustedEnvironment%29) running the database in trusted environment rather than focusing on auth options.

Comment: Is any environment trusted? Every year there is another massive data breach because a mongodb doesn't have a password. Why not have a password? Is it really that inconvenient? Is it more inconvenient than your entire database being leaked? Add any form of auth to protect against accidental public exposure, a vulnerabillity in your "trusted" environment, or a malicious employ.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the question is, what do you gain from running it password-less?

Even if you are running in a trusted environment, does it really cost that much to use a password?  While the trusted environment should not be breached, nothing is completely safe and by adding the password, you are adding an additional layer of defense.  So if somebody breaches your server they shouldn't automatically have access to the database.

For the same reason you would encrypt/hash user passwords when they are stored in the database.  If somebody breaches your server, they don't automatically gain access to everything.

This approach is called defense in depth.

Comment: I want it password-less because it is just a statistic service ... I understand your concern. If some one can reach my machine he/she should be easily see that stats.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is isolated that yes you can do it. but think in term future picture of your project.Later you might need to users with restricted access ,You might need user roles ,and if you do which is highly possible ,than its better to start thinking in that direction and start using authentication. This will also add one more layer to the security of your db with out costing much.

Comment: your point is right. but in my situation I will rewrite the app. I want to do it password-less...

Comment: in that case ,you can do whatever you want to do. but if you are doing some poc or if you are just learning this tool than its better to use authentication as in production mode you have to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Same machine, isolated network. I'd say yes. I do the same with the system I work on.
Only issue is if there are other computers connected to the network, that are also connected to the internet, and might not be secure (no anti-virus, firewall, etc).

Comment: Why the vote down?