# Should I secure my MongoDB Database?

Tags: mongodb, security

I am setting up two computers to run a web application. `web-host` hosts a MongoDB database and NodeJS web server, while `worker` runs some more demanding processes and populates the database. Using an SSH tunnel from `worker`, `web-host:27017` is accessible using `localhost:9999` from `worker`. `web-host:80` has been set up to be accessible on `http://our.corporate.site/my_site/`.

At the moment MongoDB has no authentication on it - anything that can contact `web-host:27017` can read or write anything to the database.

With this setup, how paranoid should I be about authenticating requests to MongoDB? The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209948/is-it-ok-to-use-mongodb-passwordless) seemed to suggest not very. Considering access is only possible from `localhost` it seems about as secure as the local file system. In MySQL I usually have a special 'web' user with limited privileges to limit the damage of an injection attack in  case I make a mistake sanitizing input, however MongoDB seems less vulnerable to injection (or at least easier to sanitize) compared with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue: If you do set-up Mongo authentication, you are going to need to store the keys on the machine that accesses it.

So assuming that `web-host:80` is compromised, the keys are also vulnerable.

There are some mitigation processes you can use to secure your environment, but there is no silver bullet if an attacker gains root access to your environment.

First I would consider putting mongodb on a separate machine on a private internal network that can only be accessed by machines in a DMZ (the part of the network where machines can communicate with your internal network and the outside world).

Next, assuming you are running a Linux-based system, you should be able to use AppArmor or SELinux to limit which processes are allowed to make outbound network requests. In this case only your webapp process should be able to initiate network requests such as connecting to your Mongo database.

If an attacker was able to get non-root access on your machine, the SELinux/AppArmor system policy would prevent them from initiating a connection to your database from their own script.

Using this architecture, you should be more secure than simply augmenting your current architecture with authentication. In a choice between the SELinux/AppArmor, I would use SELinux, since it is was much more mature and had much more granular control the last time I checked.